# ejabberdctl start result in error for p1_yaml

Tags: linux, erlang, xmpp, yaml, ejabberd

I am trying to configure **eJabberd** on my server.

I finished the installation but when I am trying to start the ejabberd using

```
ejabberdctl start
```

Its showing following error in the log file

```
2015-11-17 03:28:29.928 [info] <0.7.0> Application asn1 started on node ejabberd@localhost
2015-11-17 03:28:29.928 [info] <0.7.0> Application public_key started on node ejabberd@localhost
2015-11-17 03:28:29.941 [info] <0.7.0> Application ssl started on node ejabberd@localhost
2015-11-17 03:28:29.945 [warning] <0.100.0> unable to load p1_yaml NIF: {error,{load_failed,"Failed to load NIF library /lib/p1_yaml/priv/lib/p1_yaml: 'libyaml-0.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'"}}
2015-11-17 03:28:29.945 [error] <0.99.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.99.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {{load_failed,"Failed to load NIF library /lib/p1_yaml/priv/lib/p1_yaml: 'libyaml-0.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'"},{p1_yaml_app,start,[normal,[]]}} in application_master:init/4 line 134
2015-11-17 03:28:29.945 [info] <0.7.0> Application p1_yaml exited with reason: {{load_failed,"Failed to load NIF library /lib/p1_yaml/priv/lib/p1_yaml: 'libyaml-0.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'"},{p1_yaml_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
2015-11-17 03:28:29.947 [critical] <0.38.0>@ejabberd:exit_or_halt:133 failed to start application 'p1_yaml': {error,
                                        {{load_failed,
                                          "Failed to load NIF library /lib/p1_yaml/priv/lib/p1_yaml: 'libyaml-0.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'"},
                                         {p1_yaml_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}
```

For reference, the **p1_yaml** files are located in following directories :

```
root@ip-XX-XX-XX-XX [/lib/p1_yaml/priv/lib]# locate libyaml-0.so
/root/tmp/downloads/yaml-0.1.5/src/.libs/libyaml-0.so.2
/root/tmp/downloads/yaml-0.1.5/src/.libs/libyaml-0.so.2.0.3
/usr/local/lib/libyaml-0.so.2
/usr/local/lib/libyaml-0.so.2.0.3
```

I am not able to trace the issue. Any kind of reference will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the permissions for `/lib/p1_yaml/priv/lib/libyaml-0.so.2` for the user with which your running.

Comment: Sorry for the file path, I was trying with copy the file manually at that location. I have updated my question. There is no file at this location : `/lib/p1_yaml/priv/lib/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `/usr/local/lib/` is listed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if not add it into it, and restart ejabberd

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I reinstalled everything including your solution. Following is the sequence of commands I ran : 
`> cd ejabberd-15.10
> ./configure --enable-mysql
> export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib/"
> make
> make install`
But still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you please copy paste here the result of `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from new terminal session, check if `/usr/local/lib/` is listed there

Comment: On every time terminal login, that value would be show as blank and after export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib run command. it will show /usr/local/lib/ expected value.

Comment: And yes, If we will run this export command and after run "ejabberdctl start" and check "ejabberdctl status" than it "Failed to create main carrier for temp_alloc
/sbin/ejabberdctl: line 412:  2177 Aborted                 $EXEC_CMD "$ERL       $NAME ${CONN_NAME}       -noinput       -hidden       -pa $EJABBERD_EBIN_PATH       $KERNEL_OPTS       -s ejabberd_ctl -extra $ERLANG_NODE $COMMAND"

Comment: I don't get it, is `ejabberdctl start` starting successfully now ?

Comment: @deimus using this command : `$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` that error for loading library is solved but the problem is the path is not stored permanently, each time we login to server the variable data is lost.

And when we trying to run `ejabberdctl start` its giving error of heap memory, is there any minimum requirement of memory for it? Any reference will be very helpful, Thank You.

Comment: In order to have the value stored in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` write the same line into `~/.bashrc` file. The problem regarding the heap memory has nothing to do with your question here, either update the question either ask a new question.

Comment: @deimus I added one more question regarding the issue :  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776125/ejabberd-status-showin-error-while-server-is-running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776125/ejabberd-status-showin-error-while-server-is-running), please have a look at it and please give your suggestions.