# ejabberd status showing error while server is running

Tags: erlang, xmpp, yaml, ejabberd, centos6

I am trying to configure **eJabberd** on my server.

I finished the installation. The following sequence of commands gives an unexpected output:

```
$ ejabberd start
$ ejabberd status
```

In this sequence the **ejabbed** is started and we are able to access the web admin interface.

But after running the `ejabberd status` its giving following output:

```
Failed to create main carrier for temp_alloc
/sbin/ejabberdctl: line 412:  9616 Aborted                 $EXEC_CMD "$ERL       $NAME ${CONN_NAME}       -noinput       -hidden       -pa $EJABBERD_EBIN_PATH       $KERNEL_OPTS       -s ejabberd_ctl -extra $ERLANG_NODE $COMMAND"
```

**Update**

executing  `$ erl` giving following output:

```
Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
Failed to create aux thread
Aborted
```

Output of crash.dump

```
=erl_crash_dump:0.3
Wed Nov 18 03:16:51 2015
Slogan: Failed to create aux thread
System version: Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:85:24] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Compiled: Tue Nov 17 05:43:11 2015
Taints:
Atoms: 2005
Calling Thread: beam.smp
=scheduler:1
Scheduler Sleep Info Flags: SLEEPING | TSE_SLEEPING
Scheduler Sleep Info Aux Work: SET_TMO
Current Port:
Run Queue Max Length: 0
Run Queue High Length: 0
Run Queue Normal Length: 1
Run Queue Low Length: 0
Run Queue Port Length: 0
Run Queue Flags: NONEMPTY_NORMAL | NONEMPTY
Current Process:
```

I am not able to trace the issue, Any reference will be very helpful.

Comment: can you please type `$ erl` in terminal and let me know the output

Comment: @deimus I have updated the question with the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `erl` with SMP mode disabled i.e. `$ erl -smp disable`

If it runs successfully go to `/sbin/ejabberdctl` file, line 412 and add the option there too e.g.

```
$EXEC_CMD "$ERL       $NAME ${CONN_NAME}   -smp disable    -noinput       -hidden       -pa $EJABBERD_EBIN_PATH       $KERNEL_OPTS       -s ejabberd_ctl -extra $ERLANG_NODE $COMMAND"
```